# python - cannot write special characters to file even with utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I need to write strings that contains special characters to file. I've tried to use codecs with utf-8 encoding but I still get error:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import codecs

current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

with codecs.open(current_path + '/output.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    a = 'ė'
    f.write(a)
    f.close()
```

The exception thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/francesco/Scrivania/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    f.write(a)   File "/home/francesco/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 706, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/home/francesco/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 369, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Note that you don't need the `f.close()` call, the `with` statement already signals to the file object that the block has ended, triggering a file close at that point.

Comment: `can't encode character u'...'` - that sounds like python2, so `a` is a binary string, not unicode, which a file opened with `codecs.open` and a specified encoding would expect. Try `a = u'ė'` instead.

Comment: Now the problem is that you are not writing a Unicode string. You are trying to write (undecoded) bytes, so Python tries to first *decode* the data to Unicode before it can encode to UTF-8.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Yeah, you are right, I already deleted my comment; as I wrote it was year ago or so ... :) I remember having issue, but don't remember solution, but I solved it :) can check when get home

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to code in Python 2.7? You wouldn't have this issue in Python 3.